# Best headphones for use during training?

Tags: equipment, kung-fu

I apologize this is a subjective question, but I need the recommendation from martial artists not just athletes.

What are the best headphones to wear while training? The style of kung fu I practice has a lot of spinning and my cheapy wrap-around/in-ears come loose or fall out very easily. I like to train outdoors but I enjoy listening to [The Eternal Om](http://amzn.com/B008C8W6KY) too.

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, this question is highly subject and not constructive for Stack Exchange. You'll end up with varying answers across the board, each one with their own pros and cons and opinions. Second, unless headphones are integral and a direct part of a martial arts system and its physical training, this question is off topic for this site.

Answer (score 1):

I don't wear them whilst training but on a bicycle (only on safe paths and often with just one ear in place) - the [Klipsch](http://www.klipsch.com/in-ear-headphones) Rugged S4i or maybe their Sport a5i.

They have an oval tip and big silicon earpieces that make them very secure. As a ruggedized headset I think they would survive sweat from training and would just run the wire inside a shirt.

I did train with headphones for a while. I wanted to avoid being distracted by the drums and cymbals we use during demonstrations so I recorded them and trained with that turned up loud for a few weeks. I can imagine doing my Tai Chi to a background Om as you linked but not sure I'd do much Kung Fu!